# Data Extract of data extension to Enhanced FTP

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-extract

I am trying to extract Contact Keys from a data extension so that I can load them back into the system to unsubscribe them. I am gathering these contact keys from multiple SQL Queries to different objects and putting them into the data extension below.

I am running into an issue where my Data Extract Activity is failing. I am running this from an Automation, which is configured as below.

[image: Data Extract Activity for Extracting Unsubscribes]

I have tried multiple different data extensions, and all of the three checkboxes but I have had no success.

My Data Extension looks like the following:

[image: Data Extension Setup]

The File Transfer setup

[image: File Transfer Setup]

And finally the FTP Setup

[image: FTP Setup]

The error i get is not helpful.

[image: Error]

Comment: If you have data in Data Extension then Data Extract is very straightforward. It could be something to do with your enhanced FTP setup. I would raise a case to Salesforce to resolve this

Comment: @Maneesh the error is on the data extract and not file transfer. It has nothing to do with the SFTP at this point.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this? My setup looks exactly the same and I am getting the same unspecific error

Answer (score 1):

In case it's useful for anyone else having this issue - to extract as a CSV, tick the 'Has Header Column' and leave others as false.